# Missing required parameter when just trying to pass "user" in

Tags: swiftui

Trying to figure out why its requiring a parameter now when I was just trying to pass in a variable. Had generic text as placeholders for "user.username" and "user.fullname" and when "let user: User" is removed it runs as intended. When added however, the RowView in the previews requires a "user:" parameter.

```
import SwiftUI


struct RowView: View {
    let user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                Text(user.username)
                    .font(.subheadline).bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                
                Text(user.fullname)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.vertical)
    }
}

struct RowView_Previews: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View {
        RowView()
    }
}
```

Comment: when you have `let user: User` in your `RowView`, it means you are wanting to pass a `User` to `RowView`.
So in your `RowView_Previews` you should have something like this,  `RowView(user: User())` or similar.
`...when "let user: User" is removed it runs as intended...`, well not in `RowView_Previews` it does not.
There is no `user.username` or `user.fullname`, if you don't pass a `User` to `RowView`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring `user` without a starting value indicates that `user` is a required parameter for the view to be initialized. In the `RowView_Previews`, which is the preview for the view in the canvas, the `RowView` is being initialized without the `user` value. So you essentially have 3 options to fix this:

**1. Pass in a `user` object for the preview**

This is probably the best solution. You can pass in a new user object for the preview content:

```
static var previews: some View {
    RowView(user: User())
}
```

**2. Give `user` a default value**

You could give `user` a default value, meaning that it is no longer a requirement to pass in a `user` object to initialize `RowView`:

```
let user: User = User()
```

**3. Remove the preview provider altogether**

If you don't use the previews (which I highly recommend you should), then you could just remove this part altogether, as it is not a requirement for the app to compile:

```
struct RowView_Previews: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View {
        RowView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a variable `let user: User` so you need to provide the value from anywhere you want to call this class.
See your preview is showing an error. click the error and click fix . then provide User().
or add this code :

```
struct RowView_Previews: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View {
        RowView(user: User())
    }
}
```

Or give a default value when you declare the variable . then no need to provide from preview .
like this code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct RowView: View {
    let user: User = User()
    
    var body: some View {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A usual way to provide default data for the preview is to add a static property to the `User` struct for example

```
struct User {
    let username, fullname: String

    static let example = User(username: "John", fullname: "John Doe")
}
```

and use it

```
struct RowView_Previews: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View {
        RowView(user: User.example)
    }
}
```

---

By the way

```
.padding(.horizontal)
.padding(.vertical)
```

does the same as

```
.padding()
```

And it's highly recommended to replace the colors `.black` with `.primary` (which is the default) and `.gray` with `.secondary` to have an adapted appearance in dark mode.